# Featured image not properly shown in Google+ post

Tags: wordpress, facebook, google-plus, social-networking, sharing

I'm having a issue with my WP site since featured images aren't shown when I share a post in my Google+ page. [This](http://dynamotechnology.com/las-100-mejores-aplicaciones-android-octava-entrega/) is a post on the site where issue happens. If you take a look at sources you will see how `og:image` attribute is set and points to *featured image* for that post but when you go to Google+ [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/117538520378485908238/+Dynamotechnology/posts) you won't see any image on the post and Google is picking up the logo image. I've tested the post URL on Facebook and same behavior, no image at all, why is that? How I can fix this?

I'm using Worpdress Yoast SEO plugin if that helps

**EDIT**

I've changed to [Add Meta Tags](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/add-meta-tags) plugin which has a great support from developer and we find a way to achieve this using that plugin and some fixes. Also developer say that this will be include in the upcoming release of the plugin. Take a look to this [post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-set-featured-image-as-ogimage-tag) also where is the full discussion around the *solution* for the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Why isn't my +Snippet image appearing?**
>
> Images that are too small or not square enough are not included in the
>   +Snippet, even if the images are explicitly referenced by schema.org microdata or Open Graph markup. Specifically, the height must be at
>   least 120px, and if the width is less than 100px, then the aspect
>   ratio must be no greater than 3.0.

[Google+ Snippet FAQ](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/#frequently-asked-questions)

Your `og:image` has a width of 1000 and a height of 243. That's an aspect ratio of about 4.

Facebook also [recommends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) sticking to images with an aspect ratio around 1.91:1.

Answer (score 0):

My website also broke very recently, let's say around July 9th - 11th.

I am also using Yoast SEO (+ Publicize).

Google + no longer fetches any image from my website. I have the correct meta tags implemented, such as itemprop="image" (not og:image) for Google+. My image ratios are fine, my image dimensions are fine. I do not believe I have changed any setting, added a plug-in, etc. I literally just woke up one morning and Google+ was no longer fetching the image. All other social media platforms work correctly.

I am becoming increasingly frustrated - troubleshooting my website for hours, each day for a week.

I have disconnected, reconnected, re-published, re-uploaded images, etc.

My website is lawleypop.ca/shop (lawleypop.ca/design broke too). My front page, lawleypop.ca, pulls an image fine on Google+. This front page does not have meta tags.

I believe the problem is with Yoast SEO, or Publicize. However, disabling one or the other (or both) does not solve the problem. Perhaps a caching error, but I am not sure how to get Google to crawl my site faster.

Hopefully we can find a resolution. Just wanted to let you, and others, that they're not alone.

Comment: what is the solution?